# UISearchDisplayController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, core-data, full-text-search

I don't find any good tutorial or anything on the search bar.

I don't understand how it works.

Can you help me or give me a good link, or a sample code (I see the sample code TableSearch by Apple and it's definitively bad.)

#### Update:

I forgot to say that I'm working with a SQLite database.

I'd seen a lot of good tutorials abot the search bar but the problem is about my DataBase. Well, I need to mix predicate and the searchBar.

Comment: In the headline you mention UISearchDisplayController but in the questions you just ask more for UISearchBar. The tutorial cover only UISearchBar.